# Which kind of hop should be used on a First Wort Hopped (FWH) beer?

Tags: boil, hop-utilization

Should I use Aroma or Bittering hop on my FWH?
The time between the FWH and the boiling should be taken into account or it does not matter?

Answer (score 1):

I use what would be my 20 min, flavor addition.  My usual hop schedule is FWH, 60 min., and flameout and/or dry hop.  I count the bitterness from FWH the same as a 20 min. addition because that's what it tastes like to me.

Comment: I'd like to know what's wrong with my answer.